# Bijection between the power set of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ and the set of all infinite sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with $x_n\in\{0,1\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> **Proposition.** There is a bijective correspondence between $\mathscr P{(\mathbb{Z_+})}$, the power set of $\mathbb{Z_+}$, and $X^\omega$, the set of all infinite sequences of elements of $X$, where $X=\{0,1\}$.

(***Source:*** Munkres Topology 7.3)

**Proof**

Let $f: \mathscr P{(\mathbb{Z_+})} \to X^\omega$.

Define $f(A) = (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z_+}}$, for $A \in \mathscr P{(\mathbb{Z_+})}$, such that if $i \in A$, $x_i = 1$, otherwise $x_i = 0$.

We first show $f$ is an injection.  Suppose $A,A' \in \mathscr P{(\mathbb{Z_+})}$ such that $A=A'$. It follows that $A,A' \subset \mathbb{Z_+}$.

Consider $f(A)$ and $f(A')$.  Then $f(A) = x \in X^\omega$ and $f(A') = x^{'} \in X^\omega$.  By definition of $X^\omega$, $x = (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z_+}}$ and $x^{'} = (x^{'}_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z_+}}$ for $x_i$, $x^{'}_i \in X$.

It follows from the definition of $f$, that $\forall j\in\mathbb{Z_+}$, if $j\in A$, then  $x_j = 1$. Since $A = A'$ by assumption, $\forall j\in A$, $j\in A'$ and $x^{'}_j = 1$.  Hence $\forall j\in \mathbb{Z_+} \cap A = \mathbb{Z_+} \cap A^{'}$, $x_j = 1 = x^{'}_j$.  Further, $\forall j\in \mathbb{Z_+} - A = \mathbb{Z_+} - A^{'}$, $x_j = 0 = x^{'}_j$.  Thus $\forall j\in\mathbb{Z_+}$, $x_j = x^{'}_j$.  Hence, $x = x^{'}$.  Therefore, $f$ is an injection.

To show $f$ is a surjection, arbitrarily choose $x \in X^\omega$.  Then $x = (x_i)_{\mathbb{i\in Z_+}}$, such that each $x_i\in X = \{0,1\}$.  Construct a set $A$, as follows.For each $i\in \mathbb{Z_+}$, if $x_i=1$, let $i$ be an element of $A$.  Whether empty or not, $A \subset \mathbb{Z_+}$.  Thus $A \in\mathscr{P(\mathbb{Z_+})}$.  Hence $\forall x\in X^\omega$, $\exists A\in\mathscr{P(\mathbb{Z_+})}$, such that $x = f(A)$.  Therefore, $f$ is a surjection.

We have show there exists a bijective correspondence between $\mathscr P{(\mathbb{Z_+})}$ and $X^\omega$.

**Question**

I would appreciate a verification of this proof.  Also, is there a better way to notate the definition of $f$ above.

Comment: When you write "Let $f:P(\mathbb{Z}_+)\to X^{\omega}$." as a full sentence with nothing else, it reads like you are saying "let $f$ be an arbitrary function" and not "let $f$ be this specific function I'm about to define". So I suggest adding something to that sentence like "be the following function" or "We define a function $f:P(\mathbb{Z}_+)\to X^{\omega}$."

Comment: Good point: or combine with the following sentence ", defined as " maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bijection is fine, but you’ve not shown that it’s injective: to do that you have to show that if $f(A)=f(A')$, then $A=A'$. Clearly you can’t do this by assuming that $A=A'$ to begin with. What you’ve shown is actually that $f$ is well-defined: if $A=A'$, then $f(A)=f(A')$. If you turn the argument around, **starting** with the assumption that $f(A)=f(A')$ and proving from that that $A=A'$, you’ll have shown that $f$ is injective. The argument can also be tightened up a bit:

> Let $x=f(A)$ and $x'=f(A')$, and suppose that $x=x'$. Then for each $i\in\Bbb Z_+$ we have $i\in A$ iff $x_i=1$ iff $x_i'=1$ iff $i\in A'$, so $A=A'$.

Your proof that $f$ is surjective is fine, though again it can be tightened up a little: just note that if $A=\{i\in\Bbb Z_+:x_i=1\}$, then $f(A)=x$.

Comment: You are right.  Thank you.

Comment: @RJM: You’re welcome.

Comment: I am going to re-work my answer, before reading your correction.  Thank you for the note at the end.  One question.  In defining A that way, how does the A definition know what $x_i$ is.  Would I include $\{i\in\mathbb{Z_+} : x = (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z_+}} \land x_i = 1\}$?

Comment: @RJM: I’d say something like this: To show that $f$ is surjective, let $x=\langle x_i:i\in\Bbb Z_+\rangle\in X^{\Bbb Z_+}$. If we let $A=\{i\in\Bbb Z_+:x_i=1\}$, it’s clear that $f(A)=x$, where $A\in\wp(Z_+)$, so $f$ is indeed surjective.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I appreciate it.  Nice to have this place, as I try to learn this stuff on my own.

Comment: @RJM: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott Very simple and nice.  I actually get a lot out of that.  That way, you do not have to explicitly state the $x_i = 0$ case.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f$ is an injection, you pick two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb Z^+$ such that $f(A) = f(B)$, and show that $A=B$. Anyway, the rest of the proof is fine.

Comment: Oh, yes.  true.  Thanks.